# Testing useLazyQuery with specific ApolloClient

Tags: react-native, jestjs, graphql

I’m having a hard time to mock/test this useLazyQuery case; the hook in the screen:

```
const [
  getSpecificReport,
  { loading: contentLoading, error: contentError, data: content },
] = useLazyQuery<SpecificReportResponse>(
  SPECIFIC_REPORT(testResultsData?.getTestResults.testType),
  {
    client: cmsClient, // <- this is a specific ApolloClient
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    onCompleted: () => {
      setScreenData();
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      // (...) omitted for simplification
    },
  }
);
```

The mock:

```
const mocks = [{
    request: {
      query: SPECIFIC_REPORT('Report Title'),
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        allReports: [getReportTestData()],
        } as SpecificReportResponse,
    },
}]
```

The test:

```
...
const { getByText, getAllByText } = render(
    <MockedProvider
        mocks={mocks}
        addTypename={false}
    >
    <ResultsScreen {...mockProps} />
    </MockedProvider>
);

await waitFor(() => {
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    expect(getByText(/Something/)).toBeTruthy();
    (...)
}
...
```

What happens is that the screen (`ResultsScreen`) just acts as if not received the data, i.e. the first expectation fails.

**I noticed that if I take off the specific client from the hook, the test works fine - but not the screen, which depends on that.**

I wonder if I should pass a “mocked client” to the `mocks[0].request` or something - I already tried to do it, but no success so far.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by mocking the client like this (didn't change anything else):

```
...
const mockCmsClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([ApolloLink.empty(), ApolloLink.empty(), ApolloLink.empty()]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

jest.mock('../../my-module-with-exported-client', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../../my-module-with-exported-client'),
  cmsClient: mockCmsClient,
}));
...
```